# Parsing page after POST with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, post

jquery

```
$("#go").click(function() {
        $.post("i/go.php", $("#form").serialize());

        var code= ''; 

        $("section").empty().html(code);
});
```

go.php accepts POST data, then displays some text in `<section>`. 
How to get `<section>` after sending POST data and display it on this page?

Comment: "How to get <section> after sending POST data and display it on this page?"
What is <section> and this ?

Comment: @userd section? it is a html5 tag

Comment: I ask because I donno, why would you start a variable name with a '#'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not handling the response at all, just sending the request:

```
$.post("i/go.php", $("#form").serialize(), 
    function(data) {
       // do something with data
       $("#some_div").html(data);
    }
);
```